# Which sets of natural numbers are "lambda-analytic"?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, theories-of-arithmetic

Begin with a bit of notation.  Let $t = t_0, \ldots, t_d$ be a finite sequence of real numbers.  Define
$$\lambda^t(x) = x^{t_0} \log(x)^{t_1} \log(\log(x))^{t_2} \cdots.$$
for all real numbers $x \in (M(d), \infty)$.  Here $M(d)$ is chosen large enough so that all the iterated logs are positive real, i.e., $M(0) = 0$ and $M(1) = 1$, and $M(d) = e^{M(d-1)}$ for $d > 1$.

Let $S$ be a subset of ${\mathbb N}$.  Let's say that $S$ is $\lambda$-analytic if there exists a finite sequence $t$ as above such that the limit
$$L = \lim_{X \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\# (S \cap \{0,1,\ldots, X\})}{\lambda^t(X)}.$$
exists and $0 < L < \infty$.  In such a case, we say $S$ is $\lambda$-analytic with exponent $t$.

Many important theorems and conjectures in analytic number theory can be rephrased in the form "This neat subset of ${\mathbb N}$ is $\lambda$-analytic with exponent $t$."  E.g., the prime number theorem says that the set of primes is $\lambda$-analytic with exponent $(1,-1)$.  For another example, the set $\{ x^2 + y^2 : x,y \in {\mathbb N} \}$ is $\lambda$-analytic with exponent $(1,-1/2)$.

I'm wondering, broadly speaking, which sets of natural numbers might be the subject of such theorems and conjectures.  I mean, number theorists care about primes, sums of two primes, numbers of the form $x^2 + y^4$, etc.  What makes some sets of natural numbers $\lambda$-analytic... even if we can't yet prove the exponent?  This seems like a crucial sort of meta-question in analytic number theory.

For example, are all *recursive* subsets of ${\mathbb N}$ expected to be $\lambda$-analytic?

Is there some other complexity class for subsets of ${\mathbb N}$, where everything is expected to be $\lambda$-analytic?

If $A$ and $B$ are $\lambda$-analytic subsets of ${\mathbb N}$, is their sumset $A+B$ always $\lambda$-analytic?

References appreciated!  I don't know if this idea of $\lambda$-analytic subsets of ${\mathbb N}$ is in the literature somewhere, under a different name.

Comment: Certainly not all recursive subsets of $\mathbb N$ are $\lambda$-analytic. For instance, $A=\{n\mid\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor\text{ is even}\}$ is not, since its counting function oscillates roughly between $n/3$ and $2n/3$. This set has very low complexity so I doubt there is any reasonable class all whose elements have this property. I also would be doubtful they are closed under sumsets, but I have no counterexample in mind.

Comment: Thanks for that example!  Makes sense to me...

Comment: In analytic number theory the Dirichlet generating function of the set is constructed from $\log$, powers, sum, product of meromorphic functions and a Tauberian theorem applies to obtain the density from the dominant singularity.